# 400 Bad Request when Syncing large data with Sync Framework 4

Tags: wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

One of the fields I am syncing is a Ritch Text blob database field (sql server database) It works fine for smaller fields but If I add an image to the Rich Text field, even one of only 110KB, the server returns an error 400 Bad Request. below are the relevant parts of my config, any ideas?

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />

    <behavior name="defaultBehavior" >
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2145483647"/>
    </behavior>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="higherMessageSize"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior" name="syncScope5DN.syncScope5DNSyncService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="higherMessageSize" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="higherMessageSize" contract="Microsoft.Synchronization.Services.IRequestHandler" />
  </service>
```

Comment: I'm begining to think that it isn't even using my web.config endpoint. Maybe because the services use a factory? Microsoft.Synchronization.Services.SyncServiceHostFactory. Anyone know how to set this parameters in code behind rather than web.config?

Comment: Well I fixed the problem, I was using ssl and I needed  the following in the binding definition. Why this caused the service to apparently ignore the maxRecievedMessageSize tag and otherwise work normally, I have no idea:
 
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>